# IOS developer mode status in react-native inApp

Tags: ios, react-native, developer-mode

Is there anyway to find developer mode on or off **inApp** using react-native in IOS 16 and above.

I had go through many libraries of react-native but cant find any information related developer mode enabled or disabled in IOS 16.